# Wordpress copied site

Tags: wordpress, settings

Hi All i recently made a copy of a blog both have their own DB:

original site:
http://sinkholedamageblog.com/

new copy of site:
http://sinkholedamageblog.com/tennessee/

Im having issues with the linking now. Everything seems to still be pointing to the original directory when i click through.

I have combed through all of the fields in the DB tables and ran a query to replace old url with the new one.

I also ran a search through all of the theme files and nothing showed up using the old url.

Any suggestions on where to look or what to change in table 'wp_options'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following this guide? http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

You will want to follow the "When Your Domain Name or URLs Change"

Basically, You want to make some changes to Wordpress general options BEFORE you move/copy the files to the new location.

i.e. in the general settings, change the Site address (URL): to the new url, hit save, the move the files.

Once that's done, you'll need to log in to the wordpress admin again and update the permalinks.

All of these instructions are in link I listed above.  If you need anymore specific help let me know.

p.s. it says that doing a query to update all of the links should only be done in the wp_posts table since many themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL marked.

Answer (score 0):

I always change siteurl and home manually in wp_options and if necessary the rest [this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) plugin.